# calling controller action method from the view using $.getJSON(url)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have controller which accepts one argument from the view and it should return json data back to that same view.

on controller action I have

```
public ActionResult GetDataById(int id)
{
    var data = ...give me data...
    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

On the view I have

```
<ul id="#myList">
</ul>

(function () {
   var updateList = function (competitions) {
       $("#myList").html($("listTemplate").render(competitions))
                             .listview();
   };
   $(document).one("pageinit", function () {
        var url = "/Home/GetDataById/1";
        $.getJSON(url)
         .then(updateList);
    });    
} ());

<script id="listTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">
   <li>
       <a href="{{:Name}}">{{:Id}}
           <span class="ui-li-count">{{:CountedData}}</span>
   </li>    
</script>
```

On debugging GetDataById is not hitted at all. When I put alert(url) before calling $.getJSON I'm getting correct url. What I'm doing wrong here?

Update:
Route config is

```
routes.MapRoute(
       name: "Default",
       url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
       namespaces: new[] { "MyWebApp.Controllers" },
       defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: Could you show us your route configuration?

Comment: Is the controller inside the namespace you specified?

Comment: I put the url in the browser address bar, do you get the response ok? Just need to rule out the server-side to know to focus on the client-side

Answer (score 1):

What would happen if you specify the Id as a parameter

```
var url = "/Home/GetDataById";

$.getJSON(url, { id: 1 })
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a wild guess, but are you running the site locally? If so is it in a virtual directory (i.e. do you go `http://localhost/home/index` or `http://localhost/mysite/home/index)`?

You could try this:

```
var url = @Url.Content( "~/Home/GetDataById/1" );
```

Comment: nope, tried also with @Url.Action(...). Same result.

Comment: Have you used Fiddler to double-check the address that the request is being sent to and check the HTTP result that's coming back?

Answer (score 1):

I am using $.getJSON as described by Quite M. Porta's, but with a slight difference. I add a '/' to the end of the URL

```
$.getJSON("/Home/GetDataById/", { id: 1 }).then(updateList);
```

If all else fails, you could try that.